# how can i Input an image over an icon in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, icons, graphical-logo

Just looking for input, how can I input an image into the icon section of `verticalTimelineElement` for `icon = {<FaBeer/>}`

i have tried `icon = {<img src={imageLogo} alt="About" className='w-75 mt-5' />}` and running into errors

```
<VerticalTimeline >

            <VerticalTimelineElement
                className="vertical-timeline-element--work"
                contentStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#131414' }}
                contentArrowStyle={{ borderRight: '7px solid  rgb(33, 150, 243)' }}
                date="2011 - present"
                iconStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#fff' }}
                icon={<FaBeer />}
            >

            ....
          </VerticalTimelineElement>
</VerticalTimeline>
```

Comment: To help, we would need to see the errors.

Comment: there aren't any errors, its just that when you insert <image .../> tag there is a misappropriation of image data, such that it results in an improperly structured image on the page - essentially does not fit the circle that i'm trying to insert it into @AdamThomas